# Prove that a function is symmetric in its three variables.

Tags: combinatorics, functions, elementary-set-theory, contest-math, symmetry

> Let $U=\{1, 2,\ldots, 2014\}$. For positive integers $a$, $b$, and $c$, we denote by $f(a, b, c)$ the number of ordered $6$-tuples of sets $(X_1,X_2,X_3,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ satisfying the following conditions:
>
> - (i) $Y_1 \subseteq X_1 \subseteq U$ and $|X_1|=a$;
> - (ii) $Y_2    \subseteq X_2 \subseteq U\setminus Y_1$ and $|X_2|=b$;
> - (iii) $Y_3    \subseteq X_3 \subseteq U\setminus (Y_1\cup Y_2)$ and $|X_3|=c$.
>
> Prove that $f(a,b,c)$ does not change when $a$, $b$, and $c$ are rearranged.

I tried drawing the venn diagram of the sets but I couldn't go anywhere from there. This is a problem from International Zhautykov Olympiad 2014. I hope someone could help me.

Comment: I would start by trying out one particular permutation such as showing that $f(a, b, c) = f(b, a, c)$.

Comment: Well that is where I am having trouble. If you could kindly give a proof. Thanks @Code-Guru

Comment: The conditions can be stated more succinctly as "such that $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ are disjoint, contained in the sets $X_1,X_2,X_3$ of sizes $a,b,c$, respectively," no? Or am I missing something? Also, this **is** a problem from IZO, as in it's a current one? I tried googling but I can't get any information about it.

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned it is from 2014 olympiad. I got this from a friend who gave the exam. It has been long since the olympiad ended but we haven't solved it yet. So I posted it here. And I think your restatement is OK but does it help? @blue

Comment: The problem is from IZO 2014, Day 2: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/resources.php?c=1&cid=155&year=2014&sid=98dfe9f9462b330f0f3ac63cc823cc2c

Comment: @AxelKemper I read the solutions given there. But they are not clear to me. Could you clarify on it? Thanks. I would like a better solution also, since those two solutions seems impossible to think of.

Answer (score 0):

Axel Kamper's link is not working, so I am supplying a proof here.  What is IZO, by the way?

The set $U$ can be taken to be any finite set.  Note that the three conditions on $\left(X_1,X_2,X_3,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3\right)$ in the problem statement are equivalent to the following three conditions:

1. $|X_1|=a$ and $Y_1\subseteq X_1\cap Y_2^\complement \cap Y_3^\complement$,
2. $|X_2|=b$ and $Y_2\subseteq X_2\cap Y_3^\complement \cap Y_1^\complement$, and
3. $|X_3|=c$ and $Y_3\subseteq X_3\cap Y_1^\complement \cap Y_2^\complement$.

Here, $S^\complement:=U\setminus S$ for all $S\subseteq U$.

Note the symmetry of the three conditions above.  That is, if you swap the indices $i$ and $j$ ($i,j\in\{1,2,3\}$ and $i\neq j$), the number of tuples $(X_1,X_2,X_3,Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ does not change.  This show that the function $f$ is symmetric in its three variables.